# Jiddle for executing R function published on OpenCPU

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio, opencpu

I uploaded my R package to GitHub and then published it on OpenCPU as explained [here](https://pjnewcombe.wordpress.com/2014/05/31/using-rstudio-to-create-and-maintain-an-r-package-on-github/).

```
https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/github/Klausos9/test/R/test/print
```

`test` is a function that contains squared root estimation formula.

Now, in JFiddle, I am trying to make a simple Call of this function using HTTP API. However, I cannot make it working. Any idea?

```
http://jsfiddle.net/WVWCR/49/
```

But when I click the Run button, it says:

```
R returned an error: unused argument (input = input)

In call:
test(input = input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `ocpu.rpc` call to:

```
var req = ocpu.rpc("test",{
    x : mydata                        // <--- input : mydata
  }, function(output){
    $("tbody").empty();
    $.each(output, function(index, value){
      var html = "<tr><td>" + value.x + "</td><td>" + value.tv + "</td></tr>";
    $("tbody").append(html);
});
```

The error is coming because your function call passes an argument named `input` while your function is expecting an argument named `x`.

#### EDIT

The full corrected script (for the one mentioned in comments below) :-

```
  ocpu.seturl("//public.opencpu.org/ocpu/github/Klausos9/test/R")

  //some example data
  //to run with different data, edit and press Run at the top of the 
  //page
  var mydata = 2;

  //call R function: tvscore::tv(input=data)
  $("#submitbutton").click(function(){      // <--- needed
      var req = ocpu.rpc("test",{
          x : mydata                        // <--- changed; input : mydata
        }, function(output){
         $("#output").text(output);         // <--- changed; output.message
      });

    //optional
    req.fail(function(){
      alert("R returned an error: " + req.responseText); 
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. Here is a new simplified code: http://jsfiddle.net/WVWCR/54/ However, my function "test" that should return a squared value of x, does not return anything.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos, I have added the corrected script as an edit to my answer. Actually, the `click` method is required, only the `ocpu.rpc` call needed change.